# Android onResume Show Previous state of Activity

Tags: android, instance, onresume

In my project I've several `controls` in my activity `listView checkboxes and textboxes` in several tabs 
now what i've seen when i press home key or recieve a call my activity put into pause 
and the control get reset (like `listview` will have to rebind & checkbox get unchecked) 
to prevent it i set `saveEnabled = "true"`
but it `does not work for listview` Now i'll have to rebind my tabs again and fill the listview again

tell me is there any method which will save my current state and onResume will resume the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save your state in `onPause()` method and you can refresh your view in `onResume()`

Comment: i know about onPause() but i want to know how to save whole activity to resume

Comment: You need to save state of all the controls that you are displaying in the activity. Like for editbox u should save the text, for checkbox save the selected row etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such API to save the state of the activity. You yourself have to save the state using SharedPreferences or some other method in onPause() and retrieve the state in onResume().

Comment: can i save the state with whole controls not one by one please give some code

Comment: What exactly you want to save, when you saying i want to save state? 

Like, if it is checkbox, you will need to save, check/unchecked state of the button.

Comment: yes exactly i wan't to save the current state of my Activity with all controls
suppose if i do have 100 checkboxes then i want to save all of them as checked not for 100 checkboxes individually but just saving the activity for that