# how to save current state of application and return to it on onResume call

Tags: android

I am trying to understand how the android activity lifecycle works. Assuming i have an application with 3 activities, with activity A being the main and launch activity. The problem i am having is if my user is on Activity B, and switches out of my app to the phone or message app and then returns to my app, instead of being back on the Activity B ,which is where they were when they switched to another application, the application is set back to Activity A which is the launch activity.

Comment: how do you return to your app? click the launcher or recent apps and then choose your app?

Comment: @T.S not how do i return to my app. Please read the question again, what i want is to return the user to the page they were on when they left the app, but the app returns the user to it's main page instead

Comment: If your are in your app, and then go the phone app, and then you go back to your app by clicking the recent app button you should go to the activity you were. can you show your manifest anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the Android developer link for pausing and resuming the activity.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html

Also, [Android onResume Show Previous state of Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412304/android-onresume-show-previous-state-of-activity)